# How to create a new pandas dataframe from old dataframe using a list of column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. Bulk of the column names can be looped. So I have made an array of the column names like this:

```
ycols = ['{}_{}d pred'.format(ticker, i) for i in range(hm_days)]
```

Now I want to make a new pandas dataframe with only these columns having the index of the parent dataframe. How to do this?

Comment: Can you do `new_df=old_df[ycols]` ?

Comment: @CMorris: your answer gives the error: KeyError: "['**_**d pred'] not in index"

Comment: So you must have some column name `**_**d`?

Comment: @CMorris yes and it should also have data from the old dataframe

Comment: Do you just want to make a new dataframe with only some specified columns from your existing dataframe? (i.e. just filter your existing dataframe by the names of those columns?) OR do you have some new index you are using?

Comment: Do you just want to make a new dataframe with only some specified columns from your existing dataframe? = Yes

The specified column names are in an array

Comment: I understand what you want to do now: answer coming

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't forget to also upvote if you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So you want to create a new dataframe with new column names, with the existing index of the original dataframe.

For some dataframe:

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2,3],'y':[10,9,8,7]})
>>>
   x   y
0  0  10
1  1   9
2  2   8
3  3   7

columns = list(old_df)
>>>
['x', 'y']
```

You can specify your new columns by doing:

```
y_cols = ['x_pred','y_pred']
>>> ['x_pred','y_pred']
```

Here, `y_cols` is the list of your new column names. In your code, you would replace this step with `ycols = ['{}_{}d pred'.format(ticker, i) for i in range(hm_days)]`.

To get the new columns, you create new columns with a placeholder variable (in this case `0`, as it looks like you are using numeric data), with the same index as your old dataframe:

```
# Iterate over all columns names in y_cols
for i in y_cols:
    old_df[i]=0
>>> old_df:
   x   y  x_pred  y_pred
0  0  10       0       0
1  1   9       0       0
2  2   8       0       0
3  3   7       0       0
```

Finally, slice your dataframe to get your new dataframe with new column names, maintaining the index of the old dataframe.

```
df_new = old_df[y_cols]
>>>
   x_pred  y_pred
0       0       0
1       0       0
2       0       0
3       0       0
```

This works even if you have a named `index`:

```
      x   y  x_pred  y_pred
Date                       
0     0  10       0       0
1     1   9       0       0
2     2   8       0       0
3     3   7       0       0
df_new = old_df[y_cols]
      x_pred  y_pred
Date                
0          0       0
1          0       0
2          0       0
3          0       0
```